how to config category in NgDoc
I am working on an Angular project using NGDoc to document my application features. I have set up a category of features and created a page for it, but I encounter an error when I click on the category children. Here is the error message I receive:
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "ng-doc/doc-app/guides/features/login/module" from ".angular/vite-root/doc-app/chunk-AU5545JM.js". Does the file exist?
ng-doc/doc-app/guides/features/module.ts:12:43
10 |        {
11 |          path: "login",
12 |          loadChildren: () => import("ng-doc/doc-app/guides/features/login/module")
   |                                     ^
13 |        }
14 |      ]

I expected the application to correctly resolve the dynamic import path and load the login/module when the corresponding route was accessed. This should allow me to navigate to the login page without encountering any import errors.
this is what i tried
Project Structure:
doc-app/          
├── src/                      
│   ├── app/                  
│   │   ├── docs/              
│   │   │   ├── features/      
│   │   │   │   ├── ng-doc.category.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── Login/     
│   │   │   │   │   ├── index.md  
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ng-doc.page.ts  
│   │   ├── app-routes.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.css
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   ├── app.config.ts
│   ├── styles.css            
│   ├── index.html           
│   ├── main.ts              
├── angular.json              
├── package.json              
├── README.md                 
├── tsconfig.app.json          
├── tsconfig.json             
├── tsconfig.spec.json     
├── tslint.json             


ng-doc.category.ts
import {NgDocCategory} from '@ng-doc/core';

const FeaturesCategory: NgDocCategory = {
    title: 'Features',
    order: 3,
};

export default FeaturesCategory;

ng-doc.page.ts
import {NgDocPage} from '@ng-doc/core';
import FeaturesCategory from '../ng-doc.category';

const LoginPage: NgDocPage = {
    title: `Login`,
    mdFile: './index.md',
    category: FeaturesCategory,
    order: 1,
};

export default LoginPage;

I have used default configurations for everything else. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that clicking on the category children works correctly?
